# How to manipulate the two different controls on the UI thread at once?

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading

How can you continuously manipulate the text of a label, while keeping the application's UI thread responsive? I'm creating a windows form application in Visual Studio 2010.  Also if you could post your examples in either vb.net or c# I would be very thankful.

Comment: WPF or Forms?  That was the question why do I need to enter more?

Comment: To answer your question Blam its Forms

Comment: Then tag it so that it is properly categorized.

Comment: You can't do two things at once on a single thread.  You can do multiple things external to the UI at once on multiple threads, but you have to queue changes to the UI so that they occur one at a time.  You can do this simply by calling `BeginInvoke` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) to invoke the code that changes the UI on the UI thread.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx provides a good overview of this.

Comment: Your right Peter I'd be happy to give you credit if you would post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it from another thread, using `BeginInvoke`, which will alter the state of the UI Control on the UI thread.

Comment: Manipulation the UI from a non-UI thread? Did you ever try it? You would get an exception.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the .NET Framework 4 you can use Asynchronous Tasks.

This code will start something on a new thread:

```
var myBackgroundTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyBackGroundMethod());
```

You say you want to update the user interface (UI), well, because the controls on the UI have been created on the main thread, accessing them directly from another thread will throw a cross-thread exception.  You can however, start a new Task from a background thread and tell it to run on the main thread like this:

```
private void MyMethod()
{
   var uiTaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
   var myBackgroundTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyBackGroundMethod(uiTaskScheduler));
}

private void MyBackGroundMethod(TaskScheduler uiTaskScheduler)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => { TextBox1.Text = "Hello from separate thread"; },
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.None,
            uiTaskScheduler);
}
```

If you want to do something when a task finishes you can use continuation like this:

```
var finishedTask = myBackgroundTask.ContinueWith(
                    x => Label1.Text = "Task 1 completed sucessfully",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                    uiTaskScheduler);
```

Notice the TaskContinuationOptions - you can specify to continue only if no errors, or only if cancelled, not cancelled, etc (many more).

If you want to allow a long running process to be cancelled you can use a CancellationToken.

Here is a complete example that uses a background task, updates progress, allows cancellation, and reports when finished, errored, cancelled, or completed.

It is a form with 2 buttons, 1 label, and 1 progressbar.  Respectively named StartButton, StopButton, ProgressBar, InformationLabel.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InformationLabel.Text = "Task 1 running...";
        var uiTaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        this.StopButton.Enabled = true;
        this.StartButton.Enabled = false;

        var someWork = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => { DoWork(uiTaskScheduler); },
            cancelTokenSource.Token,
            TaskCreationOptions.None,
            TaskScheduler.Default);

        var someWorkFinished = someWork.ContinueWith(
                x => InformationLabel.Text = "Task 1 completed sucessfully",
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                uiTaskScheduler);

        var someWorkErrored = someWork.ContinueWith(
                x => InformationLabel.Text = "Task 1 Errored",
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
                uiTaskScheduler);

        var someWorkCancelled = someWork.ContinueWith(
                x => InformationLabel.Text = "Task 1 Cancelled",
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled,
                uiTaskScheduler);

        var resultTasks = new List<Task>();
        resultTasks.Add(someWorkFinished);
        resultTasks.Add(someWorkErrored);
        resultTasks.Add(someWorkCancelled);

        Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(
            resultTasks.ToArray(),
            x => this.Reset(),
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.None,
            uiTaskScheduler);
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        this.StopButton.Enabled = false;
        this.StartButton.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void DoWork(TaskScheduler uiTaskScheduler)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cancelTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            Thread.Sleep(500);
            i++;

            // Update progress
            Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => { UpdateProgress(ProgressBar, i * 10); }, 
                CancellationToken.None, 
                TaskCreationOptions.None, 
                uiTaskScheduler);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateProgress(ProgressBar progressBar, int i)
    {
        progressBar.Value = i;
    }

    private void StopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}
```